# dvi hdmi audio convertion using adapters

Tags: dvi

Regarding audio through dvi outputs. Something very strange happened with my PC LED TV connection.
During one electric storm my hdmi PC output brokedown. Since I wanted to have connected my PC to my Samsung TV and the PC videoboard has 3 outputs( HDMI, DVI and old VGA) I came to this solution 
I changed the monitor feed from DVI to VGA and through the D-VI, I have connected the PC with HDMI cable to the TV set. I used a simple adapter D-VI father/HDMI mother.
 The problem is that when I did that and turn on the tv I realised that I have audio signal THROUGH DVI output, ofcoures follwed by HDMI cable. It was very confusing for me because I thought that DVI output has only video signal, besides every monitor( TV LED alike) have separate audio output ( jacks) as everyones knows.
I didn't came to any conclusion yet so maybe someoane can tell me what really happened.
Thank you in advance
George

Answer (score 0):

Some video adapters that provide a passive DVI->HDMI adapter DO pass audio out he DVi port.

As you thought, DVI itself doesn't carry audio (not included in the DVI spec), but the card manufacturers use extra/unused pins on the DVI connector to feed audio for when their DVI->HDMI adapter is on the DVI port, so that audio is carried over the HDMI cable.